# What are the minimum and maximum values of $\cos (\cos x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Here's how I did it :

We know that $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$. Let $\cos x = a$. So, $-1 \leq a \leq 1$.

Now, $\cos (\cos x) = \cos a$

Let $N = [-1,0)$, $N = (0,1]$

Now, $\cos p = \cos (-q)$, where $p \in M$ and $q \in N$.  So, $\cos p = \cos (-q) = \cos q$

From this, we can say that : $\cos a = cos0$ or $\cos r$, where $r \in (0,1]$

We know that in the $I$ *quadrant*, *cosine* decreases as the angle increases. So, the minimum value of $\cos a$ will be at the maximum value of $a$ which is $1$. So, minimum value of $\cos a = \cos 1$ and the maximum value of $\cos a$ will be at the minimum value of $a$ which is $0$. So, maximum value of $\cos a = \cos 0 = 1$

So, minimum and maximum values of $\cos (\cos x)$ are $\cos 1$ and $1$ respectively.

Is there some other (preferably better) way to do this? 

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Why are you looking for a better way? In what sense do you want it to be better? If you're looking for something more insightful, you probably won't find one, because the problem isn't particularly deep.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir What I meant by better was a more concise solution or even an alternative. As  far as I know, looking for more than one methods to approach a problem is a good thing...

Answer (score 1):

Use the derivative: write $f(x) = cos(cos(x))$
that implies $f'(x) = sin(cos(x))*sin(x)$. Solve $f'(x)=0$ and check for critical points, then sift through to see what are the maxima.

Comment: I honestly didn't understand that at all. I'm a stranger to calculus by the way. Is there some non-calculus-oriented approach to do the same?

Comment: Your initial solution is the only other I can think of.

Comment: It is certainly "other", but I would not say "better". The solutions of $\sin(\cos x)=0$ are ungainly.

Comment: I don't know; you know exactly where $sin(x)=0$. it's the same amount of work as the other one, except you had to deriviate (which may be indeed ungainly)